# type var is not defined vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I found an example in C# and from my understanding there is no alternative to 'var' in VB.NET. I am trying to create a datatable that will populate depending on a LINQ command further down in my code that calls this function. I have searched for a solution, but unable to find anything that works. Any assistance on what I should use would be appreciated. Note that I do have both Option Strict and Option Infer on as well.

```
Private Shared Function ToDataTable(rows As List(Of DataRow)) As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("Title")
    table.Columns.Add("Console")
    table.Columns.Add("Year")
    table.Columns.Add("ESRB")
    table.Columns.Add("Score")
    table.Columns.Add("Publisher")
    table.Columns.Add("Developer")
    table.Columns.Add("Genre")
    table.Columns.Add("Date")

    For Each row As var In rows
        table.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
    Next

    Return table
End Function
```

Comment: `As` requires an actual type like DataRow in this case

Comment: `var` in C# just means "have the compiler put the correct type here for me automatically". I'm not sure if VB has an equivalent, but you can just replace it with the actual type name.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# uses 'var' for implicit typing - VB uses Option Infer On combined with omitting the type.
The VB equivalent is:

```
Option Infer On

...

    For Each row In rows
        table.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
    Next row
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET already has [`.CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189) extension for that:

```
Dim table As DataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The VB equivalent is simply `Dim`, without any strong typing.

```
Dim sName = "John Henry"
```

In this example, the compiler infers type `String` (when `Option Infer` is set to `On`).

In your example, you may omit the `As var` portion. The compiler will infer type `DataRow`.

Comment: you're missing something

Comment: @T.S. — Yes, I imagine I am :-)

Comment: You can imagine all you want but without `Option Infer On` your code will not work the way you expect

Comment: @T.S. — And that is the Visual Studio default. If it's off that's because you put it there. Remember to be nice in all your conversations :-)

Comment: *"Visual Studio default"* - there are few variables to that. It is only default when there is certain version of VS and certain version of Project

Answer (score 0):

Tag your questions well, in this case there is no C# issue. Your problem is your are not writing an actual type on the foreach statement. This will fix it:

```
For Each row As DataRow In rows
        table.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
    Next
```

Comment: Just as 'var' allows you to not specify the actual type, VB allows this with Option Infer On + type omission.